# `output_signature` must contain objects that are subclass of `tf.TypeSpec` but found <class 'list'> which is not

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

error occurring code

```
hist = model.fit(
            data_gen_train.generate(),
            steps_per_epoch=2 if params['quick_test'] else data_gen_train.get_total_batches_in_data(),
            validation_data=data_gen_test.generate(),
            validation_steps=2 if params['quick_test'] else data_gen_test.get_total_batches_in_data(),
            epochs=1,
            verbose=0
        )
```

full error log

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 123, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/from_generator_op.py", line 124, in _from_generator
    raise TypeError(f"`output_signature` must contain objects that are "
TypeError: `output_signature` must contain objects that are subclass of `tf.TypeSpec` but found <class 'list'> which is not.
```

now I'm practicing sound event detection paper in my local computer.
But the past keras and Tensorflow was used and I have some issues with that while training.

model was made with keras Model and compiled my below code.

```
model = Model(inputs=spec_start, outputs=[sed, doa])
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss=['binary_crossentropy', 'mse'], loss_weights=weights)
```

from the error code where does <class 'list'> probably exists?
and what is output_signature in .fit() methods

Comment: What does `data_gen_train.generate()`?

Comment: that method yield feat, label and each data type is <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'list'>.

Comment: Please show your generator class and also the model. What TF version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using tensorflow 2.16 and I encountered this issue when returning a list as following:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    X1, X2, y = get_data()
    return [X1, X2], y
```

To address it, I changed the list to a tuple, and the problem resolved:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    X1, X2, y = get_data()
    return (X1, X2), y
```